# Group by multiple columns to create frequency table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe as below:

```
data = [['A', 1], ['A', 0], ['A', 1], ['B', 0], ['B', 1], ['C', 1], ['C', 1], ['C', 1]]
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'effect'])

  Name  effect
0    A       1
1    A       0
2    A       1
3    B       0
4    B       1
5    C       1
6    C       1
7    C       1
```

After doing a `groupby` I'm getting:

```
temp_df.groupby(['Name','effect']).size().reset_index(name='count')

  Name  effect  count
0    A       0      1
1    A       1      2
2    B       0      1
3    B       1      1
4    C       1      3
```

But I need my result to look like a frequency table:

| Name | e0 | e1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| C | 0 | 3 |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cross-tabulate with [**`crosstab()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html). To add `e` to the column names, chain [**`add_prefix()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```py
pd.crosstab(temp_df.Name, temp_df.effect).add_prefix('e')

# effect  e0  e1
# Name          
# A        1   2
# B        1   1
# C        0   3
```

Answer (score 4):

Groupby with value counts and unstack:

```
out = temp_df.groupby("Name")['effect'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
out = out.add_prefix(out.columns.name).rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
```

---

```
print(out)

  Name  effect0  effect1
0    A        1        2
1    B        1        1
2    C        0        3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.pivot_table()`:

```
print(
    temp_df.assign(tmp=temp_df["effect"])
    .pivot_table(
        index="Name",
        columns="effect",
        values="tmp",
        aggfunc="count",
        fill_value=0,
    )
    .add_prefix("e")
    .reset_index()
)
```

Prints:

```
effect Name  e0  e1
0         A   1   2
1         B   1   1
2         C   0   3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [['A', 1], ['A', 0], ['A', 1], ['B', 0], ['B', 1], ['C', 1], ['C', 1], ['C', 1]]
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'e0'])
print(temp_df)
temp_df.groupby(['Name','e0']).size().reset_index(name='e1')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].